# Plugin, getting an entry when one of multiple category fields and/or lightswitches are not empty/turned on

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

Basically I’m trying to get en Entry where, either one (or more) of three lightswitches is (are) turned on, or where either categoryOne or categoryTwo is not empty.

This is what I got so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$criteria = [
    'section' => 'news',
    'limit' => 100,
    'search' => ‘lightswitchOne:1 OR lightswitchTwo:1 OR lightswitchThree:1’,
    'categoryOne' => ':notempty:’,
    'categoryTwo’ => ':notempty:’,
    'id' => 'and, not 1, not 2’//Also exclude a couple id's
];
$criteriaModel = craft()->elements->getCriteria("Entry");
$criteriaModel->setAttributes($criteria);
return $criteriaModel->find();
```

Is there a way to do this is in Craft?

Comment: would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found the answer. You can use an * operator in the search query to check if a category field is not empty. So the solution in my case was:

```
'search' => lightswitchOne:1 OR lightswitchTwo:1 OR lightswitchThree:1 OR categoryOne:* OR categoryTwo:*
```